# cannot read property style of undefined when using viewchild with template reference in angular8

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I have used viewchild with template reference to apply the colors in input and text html element.And i got a run time error when i ran the program.

I'm using using angular8 and ionic4.

**Error:**

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at HomePage.ngAfterViewInit (home.page.ts:21)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:28206)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:28171)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:28153)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38386)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:39716)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:39299)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:27092)
    at StackController.push../node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/fesm5.js.StackController.setActive (fesm5.js:3601)
    at IonRouterOutlet.push../node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/fesm5.js.IonRouterOutlet.activateWith (fesm5.js:4246)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

**home.page.ts:**

```
export class HomePage implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('country', { static: true }) countryRef: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('person', { static: true }) personRef: ElementRef;

 constructor(){
 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.personRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'brown';
    this.countryRef.nativeElement.style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

**home.page.html:**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter country name" #country></ion-input>
  <ion-text #person> steve </ion-text>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Does changing `static: true` to `static: false` get rid of the error?

Comment: It is not worked. I tried already

Answer (score 0):

The template reference variables are pointing to **components and not html elements**.

This means that what you actually get with `@ViewChild` are the intances of these 
components (`IonInputComponent`, `IonTextComponent`) and **not an `ElementRef`**.

```
countryRef: IonInputComponent // instead of ElementRef
personRef: IonTextComponent // instead of ElementRef
```

Thus `countryRef.nativeElement // undefined`.

If you want to modify the styles dynamically, try wiring up the components and adjust your template reference variables so that they point to the html elements which wire up the actual ionic components.

e.g.

```html
<ion-content>
  <span #country>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter country name"></ion-input>
  </span>


  <span #person>
    <ion-text> steve </ion-text>
  </span>
</ion-content>
```